# Как проверить наличие объекта в кортеже?

Tags: python, объекты

Начал разработку собственного чат-бота (ну типо ассистент windows) на Python,да бы попрактиковаться. Сразу столкнулся с такой проблемой: нужно проверить что ввел пользователь, и дать соответствующий ответ. Первое что пришло в голову - создать кортежи с списком команд по типу 'привет' / 'как дела?' и т.д. Не работает. Первый раз находит команду (одну) а на следующие - нет.
Подскажите, как можно проверить наличие объекта в одном из объектов кортежа? Не обязательно через кортеж, просто нужен вариант решения данной задачи.

P.S. Начал учить Python относительно недавно, по книге "A Byte Of Python", поэтому разбираюсь только в основах...

Вот код подпрограммы, которая имитирует эту ситуацию:

```
commands = set(('hello', 'Hello', 'Hi', 'hi'))

inp = input("Enter anything: ")

for item in commands:
    if item in inp:
        print("Успешно!")
        break
    else:
        print("Ошибка...")
        break
```

Comment: Не понимаю. Что именно не работает? Можно пример входных и ожидаемых выходных данных?

Answer (score 2):

```
for item in commands:
    if item in inp:
        print("Успешно!")
        break
else:
    print("Ошибка...")
```

Кусок кода в `else` запустится только если цикл `for` закончится сам, без `break`.

Также можно использовать словари:

```
commands = {"Здраствуйте": ("привет", "прив", "хай")}

inp = input().lower()

for key, value in commands.items():
    if inp in value:
        print(key)
        break
else:
    print("Я незнаю такую команду")
```

Функция `lower` ставит все символы в нижний регистр.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша ошибка в добавлении `break`. Если на первой итерации `item in inp` возвращает `False`, то вы прерываете цикл и больше не смотрите на другие команды. Можно исправить ваш код, убрав блок `else`.

Небольшая иллюстрация:

```
commands = ('hello', 'Hello', 'Hi', 'hi')

inp = input("Сообщение: ")

print("\nВаш вариант.")
print(f"Давайте пройдемся по набору commands: {commands}.")
for item in commands:
    print(f" * item: {item} {'в' if item in inp else 'не в'} списке комманд.")
    if item in inp:
        print(" ~ Регестрирую успешность и прерываю цикл.")
        break
    else:
        print(" ~ Регестрирую неудачу и прерываю цикл.")
        # Что значит «прерываю цикл» тут?
        # То, что этот item не найден в введенном сообщении.
        # В этом случае нам нужно ПРОДОЛЖИТЬ (continue) цикл.
        break
        # continue будет правильным вариантом.
        # Иначе введенное сообщение сравнивается ТОЛЬКО
        # с первой коммандой набора commands.

# @-@-@-@-@
print("\nМой вариант.")
'''
Каждый элемент X в commands становится str.lower(X).
set'ом удаляем дубликаты.
Получаем набор {"hello", "hi"}.
'''
commands = set(map(str.lower, commands))

print(f"Давайте пройдемся по набору commands: {commands}.")
for command in commands:
    print(f" * command: {command} {'в' if command in inp.lower() else 'не в'} списке комманд.")
    if command in inp.lower():
        print(" ~ Регестрирую успешность и прерываю цикл.")
        break
    print(" ~ Регестрирую неудачу и продолжаю сравнивать сообщение с другими коммандами.")

print("\nМой вариант 2.")
print("Определим, есть ли введенное сообщение в списке комманд: ", end='')
if any(map(lambda command: command in inp.lower(), commands)):
    print("есть!")
else:
    print("нету.")
```

```
Сообщение: Hi, Racel!

Ваш вариант.
Давайте пройдемся по набору commands: ('hello', 'Hello', 'Hi', 'hi').
 * item: hello не в списке комманд.
 ~ Регестрирую неудачу и прерываю цикл.

Мой вариант.
Давайте пройдемся по набору commands: {'hello', 'hi'}.
 * command: hello не в списке комманд.
 ~ Регестрирую неудачу и продолжаю сравнивать сообщение с другими коммандами.
 * command: hi в списке комманд.
 ~ Регестрирую успешность и прерываю цикл.

Мой вариант 2.
Определим, есть ли введенное сообщение в списке комманд: есть!
```

Comment: Shamus Rezol, спасибо большое! Подставил ваш способ под свою программу, работает. Решил воспользоваться вторым вашим способом, т.к. программа выполняется быстрее.

Comment: [Это не так](https://ideone.com/Ivhxbe).

Answer (score 1):

```
cmds = ['hi', 'hello']

inp = input('').lower()

if inp in cmds:
    print('Hi')
else:
    print('Err')
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно обратиться к элементу словаря(если они случайные, добавить в начале обязательный, типа `"1":1`) через блок `try`, если `except` сработает - элемента нет. Помещаешь в `try` действия для присутствующего элемента (советую задать пременную, а потом проверить ее значение, чтобы избежать огромного отступа из-за `try`'ев), а в `except` - для отсутсвующего. Вроде должно помочь.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Не за что) Рад что помог!